# ORDER BY column FROM another table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I want to order user's friends by ***last_act*** with them. But information about users is in table **users** and ***last_act*** in table **friends**.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM users AS m 
WHERE m.username = '$username' 
JOIN friends AS p 
ORDER BY p.last_act DESC
```

Comment: `Join` before the `where` use an `on`. Also use error reporting so you know why your query fails.

Comment: Your `select` query syntax is wrong.

Comment: Select -> from -> join (on) -> where -> order by . Follow this basic arrangement of clauses

Comment: You should look into using parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using PHP variables directly in the query like that.

Comment: Please show us the schema for `users` and `friends`

Comment: What does your table schemas look like?

Comment: We need to know which column can be used to JOIN these 2 tables rather than guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a foreign key on friends table for user.
For eg say it userid.
Then above query will be:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM users AS m 
    JOIN friends AS p ON p.userid = m.id  
WHERE m.username = '$username' 
ORDER BY p.last_act DESC
```

Comment: thanks for answer but for some reason it still order it by id of friend row

Comment: Is there any logic to those aliases? Why not `users as u` and `friends as f`?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake. I got it. I was mistake in my code. Thanks to all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague, we don't know the structure of tables and we don't see error message neither...

but is see there an order issue, it must go as SELECT, FROM, JOIN, WHERE. And you need use ON to map relation in JOIN.

example

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.foreign_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT m.*, f.* 
FROM users AS m  
JOIN friends AS p 
ON m.id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN users AS f 
ON p.friend_id = f.id
WHERE m.username = '$username' 
ORDER BY p.last_act DESC
```

Comment: Why the join on `users` when the FROM is using `users`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can't get your question. `users` is the table name :-) that is why it is in `FROM` :-)

Comment: If you leave the edit as it is, you may see the mistake

Comment: @RiggsFolly if you see the mistake you can put a comment, I'll try my best to understand what you mean. But use **edit** button to point to some mistake - that is not the best and polite practice imho

Comment: I was trying to avoid you getting a downvote, but now I give up

Comment: @Alex - All Riggs was doing was format the query to make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson someone is paying attention

Comment: I mentioned the mistake in the first comment under your answer. the FROM clause uses the `users` table therefore the `JOIN` on `users` is irrelevant at best and wrong at worst

Comment: @RiggsFolly take a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23beeb/1 and you can put any your version of query for me to understand where do you see an issue